# Displaying Dates in Readable Format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have dates stored in a MySQL database table in the standard format - e.g. 1955-07-23. I want to display them like this: July 23, 1955.

So I tried this:

```
echo DATE("F d, Y",strtotime($Born['DATE']));
```

It displays the right format, but the wrong date. No matter how I change it, it displays December 31, 1969.

From the beginning, this is my query, where PB.Born and PB.Died = the dates various people were born and died:

```
$res = mysql_query ("SELECT P.URL, PB.Born, PB.Died, PB.Birth_Place, PB.Death_Place
 FROM people P
 LEFT JOIN people_1_bio PB ON PB.URL = P.URL
 WHERE P.URL LIKE '$MyURL' AND P.Site = '$MySiteID'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Then I have this...

```
$Born = $row['Born'];
$Died = $row['Died'];
$Birth = DATE("F d, Y",strtotime($Born['DATE']));
$Death = DATE("F d, Y",strtotime($Died['DATE']));
```

I've tried a number of variations, inside and outside a while loop. No matter what the page URL, the date displayed is always December 31, 1969.

I also tried another strategy...

```
$res = mysql_query ("SELECT P.URL, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Born) AS Birth, PB.Died,
 FROM people P
 LEFT JOIN people_1_bio PB ON PB.URL = P.URL
 WHERE P.URL LIKE '$MyURL' AND P.Site = '$MySiteID'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Then I echo it...

```
echo date('F j, Y',$result['Birth']);
```

and get the same date!

I've found a gazillion different ways of displaying dates, but they're confusing. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Born) when you fetch it from the database?

Comment: I don't know how to fetch it from the database. The only thing it displays is December 31, 1969, so I assume that's the value. However, I can't find that date anywhere in my database. I discovered through Google that December 31, 1969 is a common error, though I haven't yet figured out the solution.

Comment: if you have a $result=mysql_query('select unix_timestamp(born) as Birth ... ...) then just echo $result['Birth']

Comment: Interesting, I pasted the entire query into SQL, and the value for the field 'Born' is 28th October 1955, rather than 1955-10-28.

Comment: so maybe strtotime() function is failing you?

Comment: Well, it looks like the date has been converted in the database, but I can't figure out how to display it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35231/discussion-between-david-blomstrom-and-axarydax)

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` can't parse the date string it gets from MySQL. It unhelpfully returns FALSE,  which `date` type-coerces into 0 and interprets as the unix epoch. Its then displayed as Dec 31 1969.

It sounds like your database is storing dates as strings or something. If this is the case, I'd recommend changing the scheme if at all possible.

Comment: Wow, this is confusing stuff!

I think I found a solution. I changed the query to this:

    DATE_FORMAT(DATE(PB.Born), '%M %d, %Y') AS Birth

...then echo $Birth.

However, I can see now why it's better to format the dates in PHP rather than MySQL. I'd like to change my database query back to a simple PB.Born, then do something like this...

    $Born = $row['Born'];
    $Born = date_format("F j, Y");
    echo $Born;

But that just displays one set date, also.